# Why type of left hand side ignored - Jackson deserialisation

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I have a POJO like this

```
class POJO {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map;
    //Getter and Setter for map here
}
```

And I have a json  (list of POJO)

```
[
    {
        "200": 10
    },
    {
        "20": 100,
        "30": 400
    }
]
```

During Jackson deserialization if I do

```
String s = ... //s has the above json
List<POJO> pojoList = mapper.readValue(s, new TypeReference<List<POJO>>() {});
System.out.println(pojoList.get(0).getMap().get(20)); //prints 100
```

then there is no problem

But if I use generic List like

```
List<POJO> pojoList = mapper.readValue(s, List.class);
```

then in the `System.out.println` it throws `ClassCastException`

```
java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to mycode.model.POJO
```

---

I understand that if I just tell Jackson `List` it deserializes each object as Map and not as type POJO. So when I try to access `pojoList.get(0).getMap()` it throws exception

(Note: Printing `pojoList.get(0)` gives no problem and prints `{"200":10}`)

My question is why didn't it throw exception during deserialization itself. Did the type of object on LHS ignored?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

> My question is why didn't it throw exception during deserialization
>   itself. Did the type of object on LHS ignored?

You have a misunderstanding of how Java works. The runtime evaluation of these two statements

```
List<POJO> pojoList = mapper.readValue(s, List.class);
mapper.readValue(s, List.class);
```

is exactly the same. In other words, an assigned variable plays no role at runtime. At compile time, all it's good for is potentially providing context for generics and [poly expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.2).

When you invoke your

```
mapper.readValue(s, List.class);
```

you're telling Jackson to deserialize the JSON into a `List`. That's it. You give it no other information. There's absolutely no way for Jackson to guess that you meant a list of `POJO` or anything else. As such, Jackson guesses and uses its own defaults. For JSON objects, that default is `LinkedHashMap`.

What's more, `List.class` evaluates to `Class<List>` and therefore the return type of your `readValue` is the raw `List` type. When working with raw types, generics are erased. You therefore don't get a compilation error, but you should have a warning about unchecked conversions.

You should read

- [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

---

On the other hand, this

```
List<POJO> pojoList = mapper.readValue(s, new TypeReference<List<POJO>>() {});
```

works because you are giving Jackson ALL the information it needs to properly deserialize the JSON. It's a `List` (a JSON array) of `POJO` elements (JSON objects).

This, however, has its own problems. The return type (ie. compile time) of `readValue` is inferred from the context (that I mentioned earlier) and bound to `List<POJO>` since that is the type of the expression you're assigning the result to. The `TypeReference` provides no type information for the generics here. Because of this, you can do something like

```
List<String> stringList = mapper.readValue(s, new TypeReference<List<POJO>>() {});
```

and it will compile without error. At runtime though, everything will probably break.